# Подключение к COM порту через PHP

Tags: php, com-порт, модемы

Требуется настроить отправку и получение SMS через GSRS- модем (используется GPRS-модем iRZ MC52iT). Сообщения будут хранится в базе и предполагается, что скрипт на PHP будет периодически их выбирать и посылать по нужному номеру.
  Для установки соединения с модемом используется библиотека  [php_serial.class.php](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html). При запуске скрипта

```
include ' php_serial.class.php';
$serial = new PhpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("COM1");
$serial->deviceOpen('w+');
stream_set_timeout($serial->_dHandle, 50);
$serial->confBaudRate(9600); //в этом месте возникает ошибка
$serial->sendMessage("AT",1);
var_dump($serial->readPort());
$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\n\r",1);
var_dump($serial->readPort());
$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"\n\r",3);
var_dump($serial->readPort());
$serial->deviceClose();
```

Выводится ошибка **Warning: Unable to set the baud rate : the device is either not set or opened**
Выяснилось, что ошибка возникает в этом месте

```
if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_SET) {
        trigger_error("Unable to set the baud rate : the device is " .
                      "either not set or opened", E_USER_WARNING);

        return false;
    }
```

, где `$this->_dState`, почему-то, равняется 2, а SERIAL_DEVICE_SET = 1.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разобраться с этой проблемой?
P.S. через putty к COM1 подключаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже нужно вначале:

```
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
```

а уже потом:

```
$serial->deviceOpen('w+');
```

Comment: Вы - чудо!)))))

Comment: Можете еще, пожалуйста, подсказать, почему при $serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\n\r",1);
var_dump($serial->readPort()); выводится  пустая строка?

Comment: Как, вообще,  можно получить ответ от модема, подключенного к com-порту?

Comment: надо смотреть документацию к модему. может быть не такая команда должна быть. ответ наверно так получается $serial->readPort()

Comment: Я эти команды перед этим тестировала в putty и все работало((